# Datatable and datetimepicker conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datatable

I am using date-time picker and datatable in my website.

The datatable don't work if I use date-time-picker at the same time. And if I delete the date-time-picker, the dataTable will work.

Please help me, I am not that good in customizing javascript code.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api2.prodigy.co.id/plugins/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
<script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script>


$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        , timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#register_and_login').DataTable();
} );
```

Comment: Can you add a fiiddle

Comment: There must be datatable js you using,please paste that too here

Comment: what datetimepicker are you using?

Comment: Hi,could you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, just add one of them in noConfilict() function.